# How do I copy files with two properties in AppleScript

Tags: properties, copy, applescript

I have an external device in my Mac and want to copy the last updated file of this USB-device to my Mac (for example a .PDF or a .jpg). But I have alway an .ini-file (which is alway updated last) on this device and don't want to delete this. I have tried to following code, but it does not work

```
property source : "Folder A:"
property destination : "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Desktop:Folder B:"


with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds
    tell application "Finder"
        set the_file to last item of (sort (get files of folder source whose kind ≠ ".INI") by modification date)
        copy the_file to folder destination
    end tell
end timeout
```

Another try was to opposite, but it does not work as well

```
property source : "Folder A:"
property destination : "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Desktop:Folder B:"


with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds
    tell application "Finder"
        set the_file to last item of (sort (get files of folder source whose kind = ".pdf") by modification date)
        copy the_file to folder destination
    end tell
end timeout
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to match a `name extension` (although those don't include the period) instead of the `kind` - you can take a look at the properties of a file item to see what they are.

Comment: In the future, it would help a lot if you include the error message in your post.  This will help others to identify exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This following AppleScript code should work for you. Your code was real close. I don’t think it’s necessary to explain what I did because I think it’s obvious by just looking at my version, the few changes that I made.

*Sorry about editing your variable names.  I took the liberty to rename the variables with what is called “Camel Case”.  You can always change them back to your original names if you prefer.*

```
property sourceFolder : "Folder A:" -- The Full Path To This Folder Needs To Be Defined
property destinationFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Desktop:Folder B:"
property nameExtensions : {"jpg", "pdf"}

with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds
    tell application "Finder"
        set theFile to last item of (sort (get files of folder sourceFolder ¬
            whose name extension is in nameExtensions) by modification date)
        copy theFile to folder destinationFolder
    end tell
end timeout
```